# Creating a unique ping number

Tags: perl

I want to create a ping number between 0 and 9999 because it will be used for a user to interact with other users.

I thought about:

```
sub create
{
    $ping_num = rand( 1000 + int(9000) );
}
```

The problem is that `$ping_num` should be unique. In this case, there is a small probability that when the create method is called twice, the `$ping_number` will be the same.

Any ideas on how to make a unique random ping number?

Comment: Store the generated numbers and compared against a list and when they are no longer in use remove it?

Comment: What will you do for the 10001st user?

Comment: mmmm now thats a good question

Comment: This sounds like [an X-Y Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/151987). What are you actually trying to achieve with this?

Comment: The chance that you get the same number with this code is actually pretty tiny.  Maybe you meant to do this: `$ping_num = int(rand(10_000));`  In any case, is there any reason why you can't just use a simple incrementing counter to assign numbers?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This module maybe helpful: [Data::UUID](https://metacpan.org/module/Data%3a%3aUUID)

It can generate UUIDs (Universally Unique Identifiers), also known as GUIDs (Globally Unique Identifiers). A UUID is 128 bits long, and is guaranteed to be different from all other UUIDs/GUIDs generated until 3400 year.

Answer (score 0):

Try this example.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my @random_array = ();
my $random_counter = 0;

sub random_create
{
    my $r;

    # 0 - 9999; 10000 possible values
    my $MAX = 10000;

    # Reset if maximum is reached.
    # You could instead return -1 to tell the caller that maximum number of
    # random values were already generated and create another function like
    # random_reset() with same methods below.
    if ($random_counter == $MAX) {
        @random_array = ();
        $random_counter = 0;
    }

    # Generate the number.
    until (!undef($random_array[$r = int(rand($MAX))])) { }

    # Record the number.
    $random_array[$r] = 1;
    $random_counter++;

    # Return.
    return $r;
}

print random_create()."\n";
```

Comment: why you have { } after until

Comment: @adriancdperu the until statement's only purpose is to get a unique random number so { } is there to do nothing.

Comment: @adriancdperu I've seen your edit by the way but I made the correction already sooner.